# R/Stata Can I include a categorical variable in a Logistic regression when one of its values perfectly predicts one of the outcomes?

Tags: r, logistic, stata, probit, separation

Suppose I have the following data

```
    df = data.table('y'= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0), 'x' = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

where x = 0 perfectly predicts y = 0. I thought this means that I can't include x as a regressor, but R apparently has no problem with this

```
    logitcontrol = list(maxit = 100)
    logitmodel <- glm(outcomevar ~., data = train_data, family = binomial(link = 'logit'),  control = logitcontrol)

    summary(logitmodel)
```

But Stata would drop the last two observations because x==0 perfectly predicts y==0, and then it would drop x because all that's left is x==1. Intuitively, I think Stata's solution makes sense, but how come R doesn't have a problem producing a result in this case?

Also, in general, does it make mathematical sense to include a variable like x where one of the values of x perfectly predicts a value of the dependent variable? My intuition is 'no', but I'm not sure...

BTW, it doesn't make a difference if I add in another regressor say z.

Comment: This data does not satisfy the definition of separation. See the tag wiki for more information.

Comment: @Sycorax According to this website: (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/)  this is not complete separation but quasi-separation. I.e. x==0 perfectly predicts y==0. I'm just wondering why R is not giving me any error when Stata drops these observations.

Comment: I would wonder, instead, why Stata is dropping those observations.

Answer (score 1):

*Q1 Stata would drop the last two observations because x==0 ...*

In my opinion Stata's behaviour doesn't make any sense. If you include a variable in a regression model is because you don't know the relation between the predictor and the predicted. Your sample does not have all the population and, therefore, you cannot conclude $x=0 => y=0$. In fact if you predict the outcome for $x=0$ you don't obtain $0$ but $8\cdot10^{-9}$. If you would like a rule you should use another kind of model (decision tree, association rule,...)

*Q2 Also, in general, does it make mathematical sense to include a variable like x where one of the values of x perfectly predicts a value of the dependent variable?*

If you know **for sure (100% of the cases)** that $A=>B$ you should use that information before the model and get rid of that observations. For instance, it probably doesn't make sense to model the gas emissions of a car that is off (they are always 0). However, if that relation is uncertain, you should always include the predictor variable in the model (that is what statistics are about).